# Learning to code with Python

Tags: python

Can anyone recommend any online courses for Python?  The MSc in GIS I hope to start later this year has Python programming modules, but you can substitute with an Environmental module if you so wish.  I would like to have a go at Python before I commit to that module within the MSc, as I have no previous programming experience

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately, recommendation requests are off-topic here, because they are more discussion-oriented, and that does not fit our "Focused question/Best answer" model. College campuses abound with Intro to Programming opportunities, and the Computer Science department might even have handouts.

Answer (score 1):

In [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/catalog/language/python) you can find one free Python course and many with paid plan courses. I have done a free course 3-4 years ago and it was a good start for understanding code in Python by writing small programs from this course. Also, I have done the course on mobile app "SoloLearn" (find for your platform). I was doing the tasks from the course while riding on public transportation.

Anyway, I also I would advise to read a book along with it. 
Mark Lutz wrote this [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do). I think it is the top of Python's books. With this book you may understand all about Python, but reading this book will take a long time.

Also, there are many other good book about python like [Dive into the Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224150), [Essential Python Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329786) or even [Python for Kids](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593274076). You can find many books about Python for any experience level and subject (web, GIS, data science, image processing, etc.)

As for GIS [here](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/python-geospatial-development-second-edition) is a very good Python Geospatial Development book.
This book would be good if you have some experience with geospatial data because you may understand all examples and goals. But it's not for a beginner with coding on Python.